# Android:Restful webservice put method showing response with status 405 Method not allowed

Tags: rest

I am getting data by http get through restful webservice hosted on IIS7 but when i am trying to put data i am having problem

MY code for put is as follows:

```
public Void put(String url, List<NameValuePair> data)
    {
        String response="";

         HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
         String dataString=data.toString();
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dataString, "UTF-8");
                entity.setContentType("x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                put.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse httpResponse1 = httpclient.execute(put);
                StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse1.getStatusLine();

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }

    }
```

The response i am getting is 405 Method not allowed, Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to uncheck webdave feature from the IIS menu which is in the window's features